# MutableState variable cannot be changed again on the subsequent click of Jetpack Compose Checkbox in Beta02, but works on Beta01

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple Jetpack Compose checkbox (modified slightly from the Compose Template Sample design from Android Studio Preview Canary 11), when it check it will switch from false to true and vice versa...

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val darkMode = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            ExperimentTheme(darkMode.value) {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    DarkModeCheckBox(darkMode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DarkModeCheckBox(darkMode: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    Row {
        Checkbox(
            checked = darkMode.value,
            onCheckedChange = { checked -> darkMode.value = checked },
        )
    }
}
```

As it switch, it will change the color mode from LightMode to DarkMode and vice versa, as shown in GIF below.

[image]

This works in

```
compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
// and
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
```

However when I move it to

```
compose_version = '1.0.0-beta02'
// and
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31"
```

It can only switch from false to true once. Then the value stuck and not changeable with the subsequent click. Is it because in `1.0.0-beta02` the behavior of changing mutable state is different now? If it has changed, how should I fix the above?

Comment: It works without issues in beta03.

Comment: Nice. Guess it was a bug in beta02 then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works without issues with `1.0.0-beta03`.

There is a bug on MaterialTheme in beta02 [fixed in beta03](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1636460/).